# remmina 1.2.31 cannot connect RDP ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_FAILED [0x00020006]

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, remmina

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64,  and remmina v1.2.31.

Trying to RDP with remmina from Ubuntu to Windows8.1 pro laptop that is on the same wired network and subnet as ubuntu.

Remmina fails to connect, trace shows ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_FAILED [0x00020006].

I don't know what that error code means.

Around a month ago it used to work fine with Remmina 1.1.2 but that also began to fail today so I tried v1.2.31.

The updated version also fails, with a shorter timeout, and better diagnostics maybe.

After googling, I tried these below suggested solutions (killing remmina each time), to no effect (same symptom):

```
rm -f ~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts

rm -fr ~/.remmina

rm -fr ~/cache/remmina

rm -fr ~/.config/remmina


For the connection, instead of security=negotiate, try NLA, try RDP
```

Trace output shows

```
~$ export WLOG_LEVEL=trace


Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[15:12:33:473] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.channels.cliprdr.client] - VirtualChannelEntryEx
[15:12:33:473] [8712:9958] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.channels.drdynvc.client] - VirtualChannelEntryEx
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx drdynvc
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Enabling security layer negotiation: TRUE
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Enabling restricted admin mode: FALSE
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Enabling RDP security: TRUE
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Enabling TLS security: FALSE
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Enabling NLA security: FALSE
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Enabling NLA extended security: FALSE
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.nego] - state: NEGO_STATE_RDP
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Attempting RDP security
[15:12:33:474] [8712:9958] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core] - connecting to peer 192.168.1.3
[15:12:48:482] [8712:9958] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_set_last_error ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_FAILED [0x00020006]
[15:12:48:482] [8712:9958] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - failed to connect to 192.168.1.3
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

The version details of remmina are:

```
~$ remmina --full-version
StatusNotifier/Appindicator support: your desktop does support it and libappindicator is compiled in remmina. Good!
Remmina - 1.2.31 (git n/a)
NAME                TYPE            DESCRIPTION                                                     PLUGIN AND LIBRARY VERSION
RDP                 Protocol        RDP - Remote Desktop Protocol                                   RDP Plugin: 1.2.31 (git n/a), Compiled with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev3 (n/a), Running with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev3 (rev n/a), H264: Yes
RDPF                File            RDP - RDP File Handler                                          RDP Plugin: 1.2.31 (git n/a), Compiled with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev3 (n/a), Running with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev3 (rev n/a), H264: Yes
RDPS                Preference      RDP - Preferences                                               RDP Plugin: 1.2.31 (git n/a), Compiled with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev3 (n/a), Running with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev3 (rev n/a), H264: Yes
SFTP                Protocol        SFTP - Secure File Transfer                                     1.2.31    
SSH                 Protocol        SSH - Secure Shell                                              1.2.31    
VNC                 Protocol        VNC - VNC viewer                                                1.2.31    
VNCI                Protocol        VNCI - VNC viewer listen mode                                   1.2.31    
glibsecret          Secret          GNOME libsecret
```

Answer (score 1):

Doh!

Solution found.

The target-laptop had its wired ethernet adapter network configured in Windows with Network-Type (network category) PUBLIC.   Changing this to PRIVATE allowed remmina and RDP to work correctly.

Evidently the network had changed within the past month.

Comment: I face same issue with Windows 10, even time after i set it up in two days I could not get it connected i;m running it on DigitalOcean droplet